# Neo4j delete all the nodes in a label and their relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know this question has been asked many times but the answers didn't solve my problem.
I want to delete all the nodes in the label TelephoneNumber and their relationships (millions).
I have tried first deleting the relationships this way:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[r:HAS_TELEPHONE_NUMBER]->(:TelephoneNumber)
DELETE r
```

But after certain amount of time I get an error `GC overhead limit exceeded`. I have tried limiting the query like this:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[r:HAS_TELEPHONE_NUMBER]->(:TelephoneNumber)
WITH r LIMIT 100
DELETE r
```

But I get the same error.
I have tried another way:

```
MATCH (t:TelephoneNumber) OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r]-()
DELETE t,r
```

But I get the same error again.
How can I delete all the nodes in the label and their relationships without exceeding the garbage collector overhead limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take advantage of APOC Procedures [apoc.periodic.commit()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit). Also, since you're wanting to delete nodes, DETACH DELETE will help, as this will delete all relationships from the node and then delete the node itself.

An example of usage might be:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (tel:TelephoneNumber)
with tel limit {limit}
detach delete tel
return count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

You can adjust the batch size limit as necessary, but 10000 usually works.

Comment: As a quick update, for most cases of periodic batching, `apoc.periodic.iterate()` should nearly always be used instead, as it's easier to use and more efficient.